# Compound Poisson Process property:$\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}}_{i=1}J_i \leq n)=\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}}_{i=N_{t_3}+1}J_i \leq n)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am trying to demostrate that the Compound Poisson Process has independent increments, and I have a problen because I have to use that:
:$$\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}}_{i=1}J_i  \leq n)=\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}}_{i=N_{t_3}+1}J_i  \leq n)$$

But I do not know how to demostrate or argue it. For it, I can use all the properties of the Poisson Process.

Answer (score 1):

We show that $X_{t+s}-X_t$ is independent of $X_t$ (this can be extended to any finite number of increments and will suffice to show independence of increments).

A valid definition of independence is that 
$$
\mathbb E[f(X_{t+s}-X_t)g(X_t)] = \mathbb E[f(X_{t+s}-X_t)]\mathbb E[g(X_t)]
$$
for any pair $f, g$ of bounded Borel-functions.

We have
$$
X_{t+s} -X_t  = \sum^{N_{t+s}}_{i=N_t+1}J_i
$$
The number of jumps in $[t, t+s]$ is $N_{t+s} - N_t$, which is a Poisson increment and hence is independent of of $N_u$ for $u\leq t$. The jumps are also all independent, so conditioned on the number of jumps in the interval $[0, t]$, $f(X_{t+s}-X_t)$ and $g(X_t)$ are independent. Hence

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[f(X_{t+s}-X_t)g(X_t)] &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[f(X_{t+s}-X_t)g(X_t)\mid N_t\leq n]]\\
&= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[f(X_{t+s}-X_t)\mid N_t\leq n]\mathbb E[g(X_t)\mid N_t\leq n]]\\
&= \mathbb E[f(X_{t+s}-X_t)]\mathbb E[g(X_t)]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I understand what you are explaining, but with that, I don´t get to know how to demosnstrate "analitycally"

Comment: @Edin_91 I have revised my answer to a more rigorous argument